# How to write own package for recipe in arago project build

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, openembedded, bitbake

How can i write own package for recipe in arago project build? I know little bit that it can be bitbake files. But how can i write, no idea. I searched on internet, but failed to find any good source to start. can someone provide me link or example to start?

Regards
Linux Learner.

Answer (score 6):

**Create own recipe with Yocto using Bitbake:**

Use Yocto Project for Embedded systems. It's documentation and support is awesome. You can get started [Yocto Project](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html).

Build your own recipe(for the first time build takes quiet good amount of time)

**Getting Yocto Project:**

Follow step-by-step procedure given [Gumstix-YoctoProject-Repo](https://github.com/gumstix/Gumstix-YoctoProject-Repo) till `bitbake gumstix-console-image`

Now you got yocto project on your machine. Start writing your own recipes. I will show you how to create a hello world recipe.

1) goto `/yocto/poky/<create a folder as meta-robot>` 
2) goto `/yocto/poky/meta-robot/<create a folder as /recipes-robot> and <another folder /conf>` 
3) goto `/yocto/poky/meta-robot/recipes-robot/<create another folder /hello>` 
4) goto `/yocto/poky/meta-robot/recipes-robot/hello/<create a file as 'hello_2.7.bb'>` 
5) Paste this in your `hello_2.7.bb`

```
DESCRIPTION = "GNU Helloworld application" 
SECTION = "examples" 
LICENSE = "GPLv3+" 
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504" 
PR = "r0" 
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "fc01b05c7f943d3c42124942a2a9bb3a"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "fd593b5bcf6d1bb6d7d1bb7eefdccdc0010cf2c4985ccb445ef490f768b927c0"
SRC_URI = "ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.gz" 
inherit autotools gettext
```

6) goto `/yocto/poky/meta-robot/conf/<create a file as layer.conf>` 
7) paste this in your `layer.conf` file

```
# We have a conf directory, append to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have a recipes directory, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-robot"
BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-robot := "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-robot = "7"
```

8) Open `/yocto/build/conf/bblayers.conf` file 
9) Add your recipe folder path in `bblayers` file 
   ex: `/home/xyz/yocto/poky/meta-robot \` 
10) open `/yocto/poky/meta-gumstix-extras/recipes-images/gumstix/gumstix-console-image.bb` file and under `TOOLS_INSTALL` add your recipe name i.e.`hello \` 
11) Open your terminal type $ `cd /yocto` 
12) $ `source ./poky/oe-init-build-env` 
13) type `bitbake gumstix-console-image`

That's it. Your image with your own package will be ready in some time.

You can find your image in `/yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/`

All the Best.

Comment: First of Thanks Zafrullah Syed.                                      SRC_URI[md5sum],SRC_URI[sha256sum] have some value as you mentioned. But these value will change as i will make my own recipe. whatever, i am thinking, values are depended on data(content of files) check sum. how can i know proper value for my recipe?

Comment: If you are recipe location is on local storage, you can directly generate md5 and sha256 values and add them to your recipe. If you are using your recipes from a remote location say github then you can download your recipe file and generate these values. or, if you are using yor own recipes you can ignore these values also by just commenting like `#LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://README;md5=6ae88ed4026269f1ce69f4c800f36c2b" `

Comment: How can i generate md5 and sha256?

Comment: `$ md5sum filename `
`$ sha256 filename `

Add these two in your recipe.

Answer (score 2):

Arago is a distribution based on OpenEmbedded project and Bitbake build tool. Logically, you should start with [Bitbake manual](http://docs.openembedded.org/bitbake/html/) and [OpenEmbedded manual](http://docs.openembedded.org/usermanual/usermanual.html). These are slightly outdated, but still relevant in most part. After that, there is a good, simple tutorial found [here](http://hambedded.org/blog/2012/11/24/from-bitbake-hello-world-to-an-image/).

Also I find **#oe** channel on FreeNode to be very useful.

EDIT: There is a newer [manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) for Yocto/Poky that also covers Bitbake and OpenEmbedded.

Comment: Then which one the latest distributor in embedded system?

Comment: @EmbeddedProgrammer you should choose the one based on your needs. If you use arm based hardware, Angstrom or Arago is the (probably) easiest way to go as TI itself contributes a lot to these projects. Alternative way is Poky which is more platform independent.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the other guy has answered to create a new recipe is actually creating a layer.

You can do it by

```
$ . ./setup-environment build-dir

$ yocto-layer create custom  #here you may change the name to your custom layer name.
```

If you do this, it will automatically ask you to create an example recipe for you.

But I guess that's not the question.

You need to change or customize .bb file.

It has few fields namely

SOURCE_URI=" "

This is the one where you are getting the source tar file for the package.

Then do_compile = " " and do_install = " ". This may not be easy for a newbee like you and me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recipe using create-recipe or recipetool.

Check the below link for their usage

http://ashversity.blogspot.in/2016/02/creating-new-yocto-recipe.html