# Bitbake - Default BB base.bbclass does not define a useful default task?

Tags: bitbake

I have a build question about bitbake as below:

(1) I install bitbake in my default folder : `/home/xiang/bitbake`, and set'`BBPATH`' to `/home/xiang/bitbake`

(2) Created two files for compiling:

```
/home/xiang/bbtest/hello.c
/home/xiang/bbtest/hello.bb
```

For hello.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
   printf("hello world.\n");
}
```

For hello.bb

```
XFILES=/home/xiang/bbtest/hello.c
do_mybuild() {
   ${CC} ${CFLAGS} $(LDFLAGS} $(XFILES} -o helloworld
}
```

How to fix this issue? And how to add more independent tasks in different bb files and control them?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you should write a recipe. Please follow from Step 1 as shown here: [Create your own Bitbake recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974858/how-to-write-own-package-for-recipe-in-arago-project-build/19710162#19710162)

The above link is Bitbake with Yocto. You can follow similiar procedure for other distributions also. For more information follow this manual [Bitbake User Manual](http://docs.openembedded.org/bitbake/html/)

Cheers!